# What is the right value of GPIO_BASE in Linux kernel for Pi?

Tags: raspbian, kernel

According to "BCM2835 ARM Peripherals" page 90, the GPIO registers start from 0x 7E20 0000.
While according to kernel file: arch/arm/mach-bcm2708/include/mach/platform.h, as below.

```
#define BCM2708_PERI_BASE        0x20000000
...
#define GPIO_BASE                (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x200000) /* GPIO */
```

So GPIO_BASE = 0x 2020 0000.

Which one is right?
Could anyone help?
Thanks!

I find below part from "BCM2835 ARM Peripherals", page 6. I think it can answer my question.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct.

Depends on context.

Given that your context is not GPU use 0x20000000.

Comment: Thank you! I update my post of more info from the spec, and it could answer my question in details.

Answer (score 0):

Address Mapping Done  in two context
1.VC CPU BUS Address
2.ARM PHysical Address
3.ARM Virtual Address

Case 0 :
VC CPU BUS Address----------->ARM PHysical Address
0x7Ennnnnn ------------------->0x20nnnnnn

Case 1 :
ARM PHysical Address ------------>ARM Virtual Address
0x20000000 ----------------------->0xF2000000.